# paintComponent does not work on the East Panel, on West is ok

Tags: java, paintcomponent

i have no idea why paintComponent gets called for the WestPanel, but wont work for the East Panel... even if the code is similar. Pls some help.

```
     public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

        public static final int WIDTH = 1664;
        public static final int HEIGHT= 1088;
        public static final int TILE_W = 64;
        public static final int TILE_H = 64;
        private CenterPanel cP;
        private WestPanel wP;
        private EastPanel eP;
        /*private NorthPanel nP;
        private SouthPanel sP;*/



        public MyFrame(){

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            setTitle("Chuta");
            setResizable(false);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);




            cP = new CenterPanel();
            add(cP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            wP = new WestPanel();
            add(wP, BorderLayout.WEST);
            eP = new EastPanel();
            add(eP, BorderLayout.EAST);


            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
        }
```

This west panel is drawing .
        package frame;

```
    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import static frame.MyFrame.*;

    public class WestPanel extends JPanel {



        private int wCP;


        public WestPanel(){

            wCP=3*TILE_W;



            Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
            size.width = wCP;
            setPreferredSize(size);
            setBackground(new Color(0, 115, 102));

            new CardGrid(TILE_W/2);

        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            g2d.setColor(Color.white);
            for (int y = TILE_H ; y < TILE_H*15; y+=TILE_H*3) {
                g2d.drawRect(TILE_W / 2, y, 120, TILE_H * 3);
            }


        }
```

This East panel is not drawing

```
    import static frame.MyFrame.TILE_W;
    import static frame.MyFrame.TILE_H;
    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class EastPanel extends JPanel {

    private int eCP;


    public EastPanel(){

        eCP=3*TILE_W;
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = eCP;
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 112, 102));

        new CardGrid(MyFrame.WIDTH-120-TILE_W/2);


    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        for (int y = TILE_H ; y < TILE_H*15; y+=TILE_H*3) {
            g2d.drawRect(MyFrame.WIDTH- 120 -TILE_W / 2, y, 120, TILE_H * 3);
        }
      }


   }
```

Comment: You're probably painting outside the context of the viewable area of the component. Remember, a component has its own area of context, 0x0xwidthxheight. You shouldn't be using MyFrame.WIDTH in you components

Answer (score 0):

The `Graphics` context is automatically configured so that position `0x0` represents the top/left corner of the component

This means when you using something like `MyFrame.WIDTH - 120`, you will be painting beyond the visible bounds of the component.

Remember, a component has its own area of context, `0x0xwidthxheight`. You shouldn't be using `MyFrame.WIDTH` in you components